# I want to open a url using inbuilt Android system web view like the below image

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, webview

[image: Image here]

I want to open a web page without leaving my app

**Any answers are highly appreciated**

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

To open a url in webview just add WebView to your xml. and then do this.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

The image you have above is a chromecustomtab though. So to do that you want to add this to your app level build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0'
```

Then open a url like this:

```
String url = ¨https://paul.kinlan.me/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: While using "this" in last line it gets error 

Wrong 1st argument type. Found : 'java.lang.Runnable', required 'android.app.activity'

Comment: you are executing it inside a runnable. use ActivityName.this instead. Replacing ActivityName with whatever activity your in

Comment: i use MainActivity.this it still crashing